# java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: myApp : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class myApp) On Linux

Tags: java, linux, tomcat

Recently I am the facing problem with Apache Tomcat 6.0.35 on Linux Centos.
I am getting the error -

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: myApp : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class myApp)
```

When I give the command -

```
java -version
```

It Shows

```
java version "1.6.0_22"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.10.9) (rhel-1.28.1.10.9.el5_8-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode)
```

Similarly When I give the command -

```
javac -version
```

It shows -

```
javac 1.6.0_22
```

To locate the Java I give the command -

```
whereis java
```

The output is -

```
java: /usr/bin/java /etc/java /usr/lib/java /usr/share/java /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz
```

And for

```
which java
```

It displays -

```
/usr/bin/java
```

Also for

```
which javac
```

Output is

```
/usr/bin/javac
```

Where **myApp** is java project developed in Windows and Uploaded the WAR file in Tomcats' **webapp** directory on **Linux**.

I am not getting what is happening? Please can anybody please help me to resolve the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a Java 7 runtime, not Java 6.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file#General_layout for some details concerning this.

Alternatively, you need to find and/or re-compile your code to be compatible with Java 6.

Comment: Thanks ziesemer for quick reply. How should I make same version for both compilation and run environment?

Comment: We'd need many more details for exactly what you're looking to do.  Assuming "myApp" is something you wrote and compiled, ensure that you're doing this with a Java 6 JDK instead of a Java 7 JDK - *or* ensure that a Java 7 runtime is available on the server where you're expecting to run this.  If you want to keep things very simple, use the same JDK to compile your code that you expect to be running it with.

Comment: Hi ziesemer, myApp is java project devloped in windows and uploaded the WAR file on Linux (Please see my updated question)

Comment: @Deepu - So make sure you're developing against a Java 6 JDK on your Windows machine instead of Java 7 - or install and use a Java 7 JDK on your Linux server.

Comment: Just to complete the answer. You can generate Java 6 compatible bytecode with a Java 7 compiler by setting the `-source` and `-target` verions. Take a look at [the javac documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) for more info.

Answer (score 3):

The exception is because yor code is compiled using a higher version than the one you are trying to run it on. In your windows machine you might be using windows 7 to build the war. Check `javac -version` in your windows machine.

Comment: Ya basiljames its true, now I am going to change my Java on windows.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your code is compiled with jdk7?

Comment: Hi Peter, I dont know exactly.